# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [Instert file path]

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue. Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

from pandas import ExcelFile

test = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Python_work\\stock\\zen\\OutputFiles\\Test_file.csv", header=0)

print(test)
```

My problem is the code does not see the file "Test_file.csv" at all...
I have also tried putting the file in the same directory as the code itself. it still does not see the file. I have used a .txt file just to see if the code can see any file and the code recognizes the .txt file has no columns which is expected. It is as if the code is blind to excel files...

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using raw string instead (r"")

```
amzn = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Python_work\stock\zen\OutputFiles\Test_file.csv", header=0)
```